# Can I access beta versions of MCBE on the Nintendo Switch?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, nintendo-switch

I've seen how to get beta versions of MCBE on Win10, but I would like do it on the Nintendo Switch so I can play the 1.17 updates early.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

### Betas for 1.17 are not available for nintendo switch

but don't fret, the update comes out in less than a week, so you wont have to wait long.

Comment: Part One of Two. Can't wait until the second one. That's where the real fun begins.